# Caching seems not to work - multi feed

Tags: rss, feed, simplepie

I use simplepie to merge rss feeds. I have two sections on this page which do the same with different feeds. i sort them. here is my code:

```
$feeds=array(
'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Belvederegasse',
'http://diealternative.org/zeitschrift/feed/rss/',
'http://diealternative.org/arbeitsklima/feed/rss/',
'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Arbeitszeit',
'http://feeds.feedburner.com/AugeFinance',
    'http://diealternative.org/nulllohnrunden/feed/',
    'http://diealternative.org/bulletin/feed/rss/',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/verteilungsgerechtigkeit',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/hochschule',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Sozialmilliarde'
);        
$first_items = array();


foreach ($feeds as $url)
{
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_stupidly_fast(true);
    $feed->enable_order_by_date(true);
    $feed->enable_cache(true);
    $feed->set_feed_url($url);
    $feed->init();
    $items_per_feed = 5;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $feed->get_item_quantity($items_per_feed); $x++){
        $first_items[] = $feed->get_item($x);
    }

    unset($feed);
}

function sort_items($a, $b){
    return SimplePie::sort_items($a, $b);
}


usort($first_items, "sort_items");


foreach ($first_items as $item): 

    if ($itemlimit==8) { break; }

        //HTML output

    $itemlimit = $itemlimit + 1;
endforeach; 
?>
```

When you visit the page http://diealternative.org it takes more than 20 seconds to load. Thats no surprise because there are lots of feeds to parse but whats about the caching? After once loaded it should not reconnect to the feeds, it should use the cache.

Why it takes so long every time to load.

Comment: Your site took 30 seconds to load for me in FF 22. Ouch! How old is your server?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things: First, by default it only caches for 60 minutes I think - I set mine to 24 hours so that it saves the cache for the whole day. The first load is slow, but speeds up after that. Also, the `set_stupidly_fast` function may possibly disable caching or something.

Secondly, SimplePie will merge the feeds for you and sort by date, you don't need a nested loop like that. Try this:

```
$max_items_per_feed = 5;  // this pulls the top 5 articles from each feed
$max_items_total = 50;  // this caps the total articles
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feeds);

// limit the number of items
$feed->set_item_limit($max_items_per_feed);
$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_duration(86400);  // refresh cache once a day - 24 hrs

// Run SimplePie.
$success = $feed->init();

// This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items(0, $max_items_total) as $key=>$item) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: member function set_feed_url() on a non-object ??? whats wrong with the $feeds array and now i use $key->get_permalink(); ???

Comment: You can pass an array of feeds to SimplePie to have it fetch and sort them automatically.

Comment: on my second feed i get:Fatal error: 

Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 375801 bytes) in ....

Can't find any variable for setting memory in SimplePie.php

Comment: That's weird, seems like an awful lot of memory... Are you restricting the number of articles per feed per my example?

Comment: Ok, i deleted some feeds, they are unfortunately to big. But the whole site is still slow. >24sec to load.

Comment: Is is possible to get just Title, Link and Feedname instead to request all data?

Comment: Sure. I did an implementation that fetched just the basic info for a blogroll and then used AJAX to get the actual article only when the user clicked on the link.

Comment: But there is no way to speed it up, i did it right but whats the problem?

Comment: What I did to solve this is write files with cronjobs and just include them. Now the speed is acceptable.

Comment: You mean "caching" the articles yourself?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use Simplepie to generate separately html files. These i save to the server and include them on the main page. By using cronjobs I keep them updating.

The loading time of the website is now good. (up to 150% faster!)

tom